# How to apply modulo operation on a char array in C?

Tags: c, math, modulo

Edited:

I have a big number that C does not have a type for it natively. I have to use a char array to hold it. As an example, I create a 32-byte array. It represents a large number up to 2 ^ 256.

```
unsigned char num[32]; // The size could be any number for this question.
```

I want to apply modulo operation on it, for example, I want to mod the big number by a small divisor and get an integer type result.

```
int divisor = 1234; // Note that the divisor is much smaller than the big number
int result;

// do something here
// to produce a result
// like result = number mod divisor
```

I do not want to use other library. How can I do it?

Comment: Said like this, it has little sense. What do you expect in result?

Comment: and there are many ways...do you want to know how to convert a _string_ to an integer?

Comment: I suspect this is a question about implementing the `%` operation in arbitrary-precision arithmetic without using a library meant for that purpose

Comment: I want to treat the char array as a big number and apply modulo.

Comment: If you're asking how to treat `hash` as one large number and perform modulo by `length`, you either need a bigint library such as `gmp` or you need to do long division by hand in your code.

Comment: Your first job: use `unsigned char` instead. `char` could be signed 1's complement. That will completely mess things up.

Comment: So you want to write a bignum mod function... related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522379/bignum-division-with-an-unsigned-8-bit-integer-c also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199727/how-to-implement-long-division-for-enormous-numbers-bignums

Comment: @chux b is actually much smaller than a.

Comment: Don't break your fingers on the downvote button, fellows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform *mod* an a large number, use *mod* one `unsigned char` ([@Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571700/how-to-apply-modulo-operation-on-a-char-array-in-c/38572628#comment64532792_38571700)) at a time.

`%` is C's *remainder* operator.  For positive operands it has the same functionality as [mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

```
unsigned mod_big(const unsigned char *num, size_t size, unsigned divisor) {
  unsigned rem = 0;
  // Assume num[0] is the most significant
  while (size-- > 0) {
    // Use math done at a width wider than `divisor`
    rem = ((UCHAR_MAX + 1ULL)*rem + *num) % divisor;
    num++;
  }
  return rem;
}
```

Comment: Useful answer to an interesting question, if you ask me.